# Can't launch my application into emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I am developping an application with Libgdx in Eclipse 4. My computer has an Ubuntu 12.04.
But since some time ago, I can't test my app on the emulator : the emulator is started, detected, but however there is a red cross (instead of a green mark) in the target field of my emulator and my app is not updated onto it :

[image]

I've also noticed that I can't create shortcut in the emulator desktop for my app : it seems that it does not exists on it !!! (When I launch new -> Shortcut -> Application from the emulator)

Does someone knows how to fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance and apologize if my question is bad formulated.

Comment: It's been a while since I used eclipse for Android dev but do you definitely have the appropriate SDKs installed and paths set correctly?

Comment: It may be the problem, as I kept my old SDK from a previous linux installation (I kept my /home partition). I have the SDK revision 20.

Comment: it displays Red Cross mark it means your emulator is not created properly, Delete that emulator and recreate it and also check 
SDK path from Windows->Preferences tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red cross means your program is not compatible with the emulator version. Such as when you're developing for Android 2.0 and have an Android 1.5 emulator. It may still run on the emulator though. Press ok and see if it runs or not. If not create the emulator for the version of Android your program requires

Comment: Thank you, you made me on the way to solve the problem, but it is not yet solved : the build path of my program is focused on Android 4.0.3, whereas I want to focus it on Android 1.5 (which is also installed). I've not managed to change it yet. How could I do it ?

Comment: @Laurent BERNABE Right-click your project, select properties, select Android in the left pane and set checkbox at Android 3.0 in the right pane. If no Android 3.0 choice is present then go to Window|Android SDK Manager and install the SDK for 3.0

Comment: Thank you, I've found how to set Android version to 1.5 :) But I've still some xml manifest errors. I vote for your answer as soon I've corrected them and tested my app. Thanks :)